# Jmeter test script doesn't work when node.js close connection?

Tags: node.js, upload, jmeter

I have a simple API upload, it is used to accept upload file from client.

```
var flg=true;
app.post('/test', function(req, res){
flg=!flg;
var returnJson='{';
if(flg){
    req.form.on('part', function (part) {
        if(part){
            part.resume();
        }
        returnJson=returnJson+',\"status\":\"0\"}';
        res.send(returnJson);
    });
}else{
            console.log('close');
    returnJson=returnJson+',\"status\":\"1\"}';
    res.header('Connection', 'close');
    res.send(413, returnJson);
}
 });
```

I'd like to test this API with Jmeter. "status":"0" means success. "status":"1" means failure. I write Jmeter script like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aijOg.jpg

Jmeter only displays all the samplers which response contains "status":"0". it seems Jmeter exclude failure sampler response which comes from else section.
http://imgur.com/bkFSpK2

How can I see all samplers which includes all success and failure samplers in Jmeter?
successful Sampler result is :
Thread Name: API 1-1
Sample Start: 2013-12-18 11:46:08 PST
Load time: 7
Latency: 6
Size in bytes: 178
Headers size in bytes: 163
Body size in bytes: 15
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 15
Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2013 19:46:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I don't like this stanza:

```
 ContentType: text/html;
```

Correct ContentType for JSON will be `application/json`

You can try using [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to set `Content-Type` header of your request to be `application/json` and see what happens.

Also there is a JSON [plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/) which provides JSON Path Extractor and JSON Path Assertion (Select “Extras with libs set” from the download list).