# JMeter automatically setting incorrect "Content-Length" header

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, jmeter

I am new to JMeter and we are using it to develop a test plan for our Node/Express server. I added two HTTP requests: one to add a user, and one to delete that user. The first request (add user) goes through fine, but the second request is failing. The reason it is failing appears to be that JMeter is setting two Content-Length headers onto the request - one is correct and the other is not. The server logs show this error:

```
{ [Error: request size did not match content length]
type: 'request.size.invalid',
message: 'request size did not match content length',
statusCode: 400,
status: 400,
received: 2,
expected: 1299,
length: 1299 }
```

In the View Results Tree, I see that the second request has the following headers:

```
Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 30 Sep 2015 18:50:17 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Length: 1299
Connection:
Content-Length: 2
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)
```

As you can see, JMeter is setting two `Content-Length` headers and I cannot figure out why (it should be `2` - not sure where the `1299` is coming from). (Also I just noticed it's setting two `Content-Type` headers as well, not sure if that is related.)

I have googled this issue and cannot seem to find any answers. If anyone has any tips or suggestions, it would be appreciated. I am attaching screenshots of JMeter for reference (sensitive information removed). Thanks!

[image: HTTP Request Defaults (Server name removed)]

[image: HTTP Header Manager (X-App-Id removed)]

[image: HTTP request for create user]

[image: HTTP request for delete user]

Here are the JMeter logs when I run the test:

```
2015/10/02 10:47:21 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2015/10/02 10:47:21 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2015/10/02 10:47:21 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*)
2015/10/02 10:47:21 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2015/10/02 10:47:21 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2015/10/02 10:47:21 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2015/10/02 10:47:21 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 10 perThread 10000.0 delayedStart=false
2015/10/02 10:47:21 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2015/10/02 10:47:21 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2015/10/02 10:47:21 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2015/10/02 10:47:21 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: /Users/ljackson/Documents/users.csv
2015/10/02 10:47:22 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2015/10/02 10:47:22 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2015/10/02 10:47:22 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2015/10/02 10:47:22 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close: /Users/ljackson/Documents/users.csv
2015/10/02 10:47:22 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Comment: Could you show jmeter.log content when you run these requests ?

Comment: Try switching "Implementation" of your DELETE request to HTTPClient4. Better via HTTP Request Defaults.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmeter test script doesn't work when node.js close connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667281/jmeter-test-script-doesnt-work-when-node-js-close-connection)